# Calling setState in a loop only updates state 1 time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a reason that calling `setSate()` in a loop would prevent it from updating the state multiple times?

I have [a very basic jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jirafaxilu/edit?js,output) that highlights the problem I am seeing. There are two buttons. One updates the state's counter by 1. The other calls the underlying function of One in a loop -- which seemingly would update the state multiple times.

I know of several solutions to this problem but I want to make sure that I am understanding the underlying mechanism here first. Why can't `setState` be called in a loop? Do I have it coded awkwardly that is preventing the desired effect?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.
>
> Think of `setState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall.

Basically, don't call `setState` in a loop. What's happening here is exactly what the docs are referring to: `this.state` is returning the previous value, as the pending state update has not been applied yet.

Comment: It's because he's calling `this.setState({clicks: this.state.clicks += 1});`, which is really a bad idea. The `+=` is mutating the state directly, rather than letting the React do it via `setState` batched updates.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that in the docs but thank you. That makes more sense.

Comment: Note that there is a form of `setState` that takes a function and allows you to access the current state, and does work in this instance. See https://jsbin.com/kiyaco/edit?js,output for an example.

Comment: Nice. I actually didn't know you could pass a function to `setState`

Comment: this answer saved my week of uploading state handling, tvm

Answer (score 19):

There's a nice way to update state in a loop. Just make an empty variable, set its value to the updated state, call `setState()`, and pass it this variable:

```
const updatedState = {};

if (vars.length) {
  vars.forEach(v => {
    updatedState[v] = '';
    this.setState({
      ...this.state
      ...updatedState,
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow, perfect and clean way to bypass the React optimization of multiple calls if setState being smashed into one.

Comment: This was really nice solution. using spread operator concat new state with old and update the state only one time finally. job will get done `this.setState({
            old_data: [...this.state.old_data, ...new_data]
        })`

Answer (score 11):

You have to use something like that:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState([]);

  const handleSomething = (values) => {
    values.map((value) => {
      setMyState((oldValue) => [...oldValue, { key: value.dataWhatYouWant }]);
    }
  }

  return (<> Content... </>);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. But tried with a little different approach.

```
iterateData(data){
  //data to render
   let copy=[];
   for(let i=0;<data.length;i++){
     copy.push(<SomeComp data=[i] />) 
    }
    this.setState({
      setComp:copy
    });
 }
 render(){
   return(
     <div>
       {this.state.setComp}
    </div>
   );
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Basically setState is called asynchronously. It also has a callback function which you can utilise to do something once the state has been mutated.
Also if multiple setStates are called one after the other they are batched together as written previously.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `setState()` method is asynchronous. Instead you can achieve it like this

```
manyClicks() {
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  //this.setState({clicks: this.state.clicks + 1}); instead of this
  this.setState((prevState,props)=>({
      clicks: ++prevState.clicks
   }))
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue when creating a feature to import items.
Since the amount of the importing items could be huge, I need to provide feedback (like a progress bar) to the site user so that they know that they aren't sitting there and waiting for nothing.

As we know that we can't `setState` in a loop, I took a different approach by running the task recursively.

Here's a example code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-5rssb

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one using the previous value to increase the count.

```js
function handleChange() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setState(prev => {
            return prev + 1
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use this concept, this works for me:

```
const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState([]);
const products = ['mobole','laptop','tv','bitcoin'];

const update_dashboard_with_loop = ()=>
    {
      let arr = []; //temporary array
      for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
           {
              arr.push(products[i]);
           }
      setDashboard(arr);
    }
update_dashboard_with_loop();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -8):

I was able to make your code work, calling setState in the loop by doing the following:

```
 manyClicks() {
   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     this.setState({clicks: this.state.clicks += 1})
   }
 }
enter code here
```

Hopefully this helps!