# React.js setState only work on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

My React Component: A form ( the render method was omitted )

```
var AddProductForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { 
            data: {
                name: '',
                description: '',
                abbreviation: '',
                category: '',
                metric: ''
            }                   
        }
    },
    render: function() {...},
    readFields: function() {
        var new_data = {
            name: $('#add_product_form_name').val(),
            description: $('#add_product_form_description').val(),
            abbreviation: $('#add_product_form_abbreviation').val(),
            category: $('#add_product_form_category').val(),
            metric: $('#add_product_form_metric').val()
        }
        this.setState({
            data: new_data
        });
    },
    submit: function() {    
        this.readFields();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/inventory/product',
            data: this.state.data,
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response)
            },

        });
    }
});
```

Every time I call the 'submit' function ( that is called by a button in the UI ), having my form well filled, the  **this.state.data** objects is all fields empty, like it was in the **getInitialState**. But when I click the second time ( and third, etc ) the **this.state.data** is all right with my form data.

I call the **readFields** function every time in the **submit** function, but only starting from second time it works. I can't realize why.

Comment: Can you create a working failing example at JsBin?

Comment: `data: this.state.data,` will not have data from `setState` called in the same lifecycle.  Return the data from `readFields` and then `setState` on success.

Comment: `getState('data')`? :)

Comment: @DavinTryon What did u mean with setState on success? I need to get the data on the current lifecycle, not in the next. How could it be possible?

Comment: @DavinTryon I understood now. You telling me to return the new_data, utilize it to send in the JSON, and then setState, to be used only in the future renders if necessary. I got it! It worked. You can elaborate a answer if you want. Thanks.

Comment: you have the data from the form to send, correct?  Just send it.

Comment: Cool.  glad it worked. :)

Comment: This is the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time