# ReactJS - REST API query inside .map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

How do I generate repetitive mark-up elements in a React component, that also require a REST API query for each of them?  Initially I had the calls completing in a for-each loop within the componentDidMount function.  But that required calling setState inside the loop, in order to trigger a re-Render.  The behavior was unstable, [and apparently that technique is not a good idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time)

So, now I'm trying to get the queries to run inside the .map function of my render (see below).  But that's producing [this error](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=%5Bobject%20Promise%5D&args[]=).

Is there a way to return the element value instead of a promise? (Probably more of a JS question than a React one...)
Or am I going about this the wrong way altogether?

```
return (<div>   
    {this.props.currentProject.Tasks.map((task => {
        return ProjectsService.getTaskBaselines(this.props.currentProject.PWAGuid, task.TaskId, this.props.context).then((baseline: any): any => {
            return (<div>{task.TaskName}</div>);
        })                                
    }))}
</div>);
```

Comment: Can you act on the final state of all the queries by calling `ProjectsService.getTaskBaselines`?  Perhaps getting the results of all and then rendering?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to query all APIs and then handle the response once all are settled.

Try this:

```
const promises = this.props.currentProject.Tasks.map((task => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              resolve(task);
        });

Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
     this.setState({
          // act on all of your data
      });
});
```

Then render `this.state` in your `render()` function.