# Loop for with loop infinite using Break? ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What happens: I have these two variables: `ScorePlayer` and`ScoreDealer`, which are the result of a sum of the elements contained in the main array of each of them `cardsPlayer` and`cardsDealer`.

And what I want is to do the verification. If the value of the `ScoreDealer` variable is less than that of the`ScorePlayer` variable, I want it to add more elements in it (`ScoreDealer`) but I do not want the sum of the elements to exceed the value of`21`.

I used the Break method but the infinite loop continues and hangs the application.

The function that do this:

```
finishGame = () => {
  const scorePlayer = this.state.cardsPlayer.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  const scoreDealer = this.state.cardsDealer.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  for (let i = scoreDealer; scoreDealer < scorePlayer; i++) {

    this.setState({
      cardsDealer: this.state.cardsDealer.concat(this.state.cards.splice(0, 1))
    })

    if (scoreDealer === 21) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your logic doesn't seem quite right. You set `scoreDealer` outside the loop, so it's never going to change inside the loop (thus the condition is never going to be satisfied). Also, it looks like you're treating `setState()` as if it's synchronous, it's not. `setState()` is asynchronous. You can't assume the state has changed directly after calling it.

Comment: Also, `splice()` directly mutates the array that calls it, so your code `this.state.cards.splice(0, 1)` will directly mutate the state, and that's a big no no. Directly mutating state causes issues and unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rossipedia state it perfect in this post.

> don't call setState in a loop. What's happening here is exactly what the docs are referring to: this.state is returning the previous value, as the pending state update has not been applied yet.

[Calling setState in a loop only updates state 1 time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time)

The reason your app keeps on hanging is that this.state's values have not been updated yet and will not be updated till `finishGame` finishes executing, as well as some flawed logic as @Jayce444 stated in the comments above.

A solution I would use while keeping most of your logic is this

```
finishGame = () => {
    // this is a copy of your array given I'm assuming its a 1D array and you can now mutate it
    const cardsDealer = [...this.state.cardsDealer];
    // if you chose to update scorePlayer you should declare it as let.
    const scorePlayer = this.state.cardsPlayer.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    let scoreDealer = this.state.cardsDealer.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

    for (let i = 0; scoreDealer < 21; i++) {
        scoreDealer += cardsDealer.shift();

        // this will stop if card is >= to 21
        if (scoreDealer >= 21) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // this will set your cards to the new values after the loop is done running.
    this.setState({cardsDealer});
}
```

given there is a lot of fine-tuning needed in the above function I hope it gets you off to a good start. Happy coding!

Comment: Hello joshua, very much thanks for your answer, but gave that error: `Syntax error: C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/blackjack/blackjack/src/App.js: "scoreDealer" is read-only`, you know why ?

Comment: woops i updated my answer its because scoreDealer was set as a const.