# setState sets the same object in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this function to check where the object can move. The number of moves can only be 2 :

```
whereToMove(x, y){
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.gameArea.length; i++) {
  var cor = this.state.gameArea[i];
  var index = this.state.hasCoin.findIndex(item => item.x === cor.x && item.y === cor.y);
  if (index === -1) {
      if (((x+1) === cor.x && (y+1) === cor.y) || ((x+1) === cor.x && (y-1) === cor.y) || ((x-1) === cor.x && (y-1) === cor.y) || ((x-1) === cor.x && (y+1) === cor.y)) {
        console.log(cor.x +', '+cor.y);
        that.setState({ showCanMove: [...that.state.showCanMove, {x: cor.x, y: cor.y}]}, function(){
          console.log(that.state.showCanMove);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the array 'this.state.showCanMove' have only one object instead of two
even when the first console.log to show the x and y of the possible move outputs twice with two different x and y.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Do not run multiple `setState()`s like that. Compose the object in your loop, then call `setState()` once and pass it.

Comment: Among other things, `setState` is not guaranteed to be synchronous.

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time

Comment: Since you are using Javascript 6 why not to use `let` or `const` instead of `var`?

Comment: @assembler I guess its something I need to get used to.