# How to display progress to user during long running process in React

Tags: reactjs

I am building an app where a user provides a file and some parameters to then perform a long running task. I have all of that working. What is not working is showing the user the current progress of processing. I have [a simple CodePen](https://codepen.io/emptyport/pen/rqqLjq?editors=0110) set up to illustrate.

In the Pen, I have a button that runs a task in a while loop. If I am looking at the console, I can see the progress printing out as we step through the loop. However, the state isn't updating until the loop is done, so in the UI the progress jumps from 0 to 5 without displaying the intermediate values. Here I am simulating the task with the sleep function, I do not actually use the sleep function in my app.

I've done some research and I know this has to do with setState being asynchronous and with React batching updates together to be more efficient with rendering the UI.

With that being said, I am wondering what the best way to display progress to the user would be. Using React's state doesn't work, and I've tried directly writing to the DOM but that wasn't working (and it didn't seem like a clean way to do it). Do I need to use some additional library to do this or is there something I am missing? I was considering moving this to a separate process and then communicating the progress back to the app, but wouldn't I run into the same issue of the UI not updating?

Also potentially important, I am using the while loop because I am using a generator, so I know I won't receive too many progress updates because yield runs each percentage point from 0 to 100. It is also easy for me to remove the generator/yield part if that would be better.

My code is in CodePen as well as below:

---HTML---

```
<div id="app"></app>
```

---JSX---

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      progress: 0
    };

    this.doTask = this.doTask.bind(this);
    this.sleep = this.sleep.bind(this);
  }

  sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  doTask() {
    let count = 0;
    while(count<5) {
      count++;
      console.log(count);
      this.setState({
        progress: count
      });
      this.sleep(500);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.doTask}>Do Task</button>
      <div>Progress: {this.state.progress}</div>
    </div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: you cant do it like that because you are locking up the main threat, use a setTimeout if you want to emulate a async task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a background process (aka a hidden window because I'm using electron) that basically acts as a server. The information for my long running process is sent to the background process via a websocket and the progress information is sent back to my main component also via a websocket. Updating the state from a loop seems to me to be more intuitive, but running my code in the background doesn't freeze up the UI and now I get my desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurring issue in development, so I hope this question and solutions helps you out: [Calling setState in a loop only updates state 1 time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time).

I would also take a look at https://jsbin.com/kiyaco/edit?js,output where an alternate form of this.setState is used. It essentially passed in a function which has access to the current state.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and used a workaround. For some reason, when using `setTimeout()` the page does the `setState()` processing correctly. It remembered me of `runLater` in JavaFX.

So this is a workaround I used:

```js
// a wrapper function for setState which uses `Promise` and calls `setTimeout()`
setStatePromise = (state) => new Promise(resolve => {
    this.setState(state, () => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1);
    });
});
```

Now you can call this wrapper instead. But you'll need to use async functions:

```js
  async doTask() {
    let count = 0;
    while(count<5) {
      count++;
      console.log(count);
      await this.setStatePromise({
        progress: count
      });
      this.sleep(500);
    }
  }
```