# setState inside for loop does not update the state: React+Typescript

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am having an array of objects which is a state object that corresponds to a user account. Just for a validation purpose if any one of the  object property within array is empty, I am setting a validation property of state object to false. Since I am looping using for loop, the setState is not setting data.

```
 this.state = {
      accounts: [{firstname:"",lastname:"",age:""}],
      validated: true
 };


onAdd = () => {

    let { accounts,validated } =  this.state;
    for(let i=0; i< accounts.length; i++){
      if(accounts[i].firstname === '' || accounts[i].age === '')
      {
        this.setState({validated: false},() => {}); // value is not getting set
        break;
      }
    }
    if(validated)
    {
      // some other operation 
      this.setState({validated: true},() => {});
    }
  }

render(){

   let { validated } =  this.state;
   return(
     {validated ? <span>Please fill in the details</span> : null}
       //based on the validated flag displaying the error message
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code. First of all `this.setState` is asynchronous and therefore you can not say when it really is executed.

So if you call

```
this.setState({validated: false},() => {});
```

you can not rely that after that `this.state.validated` is false immediatly.

So after you call `this.setState` to make `validated == false` and then check:

```
if(this.state.validated)
{
  // some other operation 
  this.setState({validated: true},() => {});
}
```

It *might* be either true or false.

But in your code you're extracting `validated` (what you're using in the if-condition) at the beginning of your method. That means `validated` won't change when `this.state` changes.

You might want to use the callback you already added (`() => {}`) to perform some other action after the state changed or just use a normal valiable instead of something related to the state.

Like:

```
tmp = true;

for-loop {
  if(should not validate) {
    tmp = false;
    this.setState({validated: false});
    break;
  }

if(tmp) {
  this.setState({validated: true},() => {});
}
```

Comment: Any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to have a separate check that goes through the array in the state and depending if the data is missing or not you can have the temporary variable be either true or false. Then based on the temp variable you can set the state accordingly.

Let me know if this works:

```
onAdd = () => {

  let { accounts,validated } =  this.state;
  let tempValidate = true; //assume validate is true
  for(let i=0; i< accounts.length; i++){
    if(accounts[i].firstname === '' || accounts[i].age === '')
    {
      //this loop will check for the data validation, 
      //if it fails then you set the tempValidate to false and move on
       tempValidate = false
      break;
    }
  }

  // Set the state accordingly
  if(tempValidate)
  {
    this.setState({validated: true},() => {});
  } else {
    this.setState({validated: false},() => {});
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is `async` function. So it won't work in loops.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

`setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.`

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time).

Comment: Any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Since `this.setState` will only be called once inside the for-loop that is not really an issue.