# Mapping over function that sets state in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use the function changeCheck to check and uncheck specific components.

When I use the function, it works correctly.

this.props.team is a list of all of the teams.

The goal of changeAllTeams is to be able to check and uncheck all of the teams that have a specific league.

In this example I want to change all of the teams that have a league acronym of NFL:

```
 this.state = {
            checked: [],
            checkedTeams: [],
            teamObject: [],
            queryString: [],
            accordionStatus: [true, true, true]
        }

changeAllTeams = (leagueType) => {
        this.props.team.map(
            (v, i) => {
                if(v.league.acronym === 'NFL'){
                    this.changeCheck(i, v.team_name, v)
                } 
            }
        )
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log('checked', this.state.checked)
        console.log('team object', this.state.teamObject)
        console.log('props team object', this.props.teamObject)
        this.props.changeLeagues(this.props.league, this.props.checkedLeagues, this.state.checkedTeams, this.state.queryString, this.state.teamObject, this.state.checked)
    }

    changeCheck = (index, name, teamObject) => {
        //updates checked team state
        if(!this.state.checkedTeams.includes(name)){
            this.state.checkedTeams[this.state.checkedTeams.length] = name
            this.setState({ checkedTeams: [...this.state.checkedTeams] })
            //sets team object with new team object
            this.state.teamObject[this.state.teamObject.length] = teamObject
            this.setState({ teamObject: this.state.teamObject })
        } else {
            console.log(name)
            newChecked  = this.state.checkedTeams.filter(v => { return v !== name})
            this.setState({ checkedTeams: newChecked })
            //removes team object and sets new state
            newObjectChecked = this.state.teamObject.filter(v => { return v.team_name !== teamObject.team_name})
            this.setState({ teamObject: newObjectChecked })

        }
        //updates checkbox for specific space
        this.state.checked[index] = !this.state.checked[index]
        this.setState({ checked: this.state.checked })

        this.forceUpdate()
    }
```

When I map over the array in changeAllTeams, only the last object in the array takes effect.

The state for checked updates for everything, but the state for checkedTeams and teamObject does not.

This video may help to understand further:
https://streamable.com/q4mqc

**Edit:**
This is the structure of the objects in this.props.team:
[image]

Comment: it will be helpful, if you can provide the structure of `this.props.team`, your `changeCheck` function modifies state directly which you shouldn't do.

Comment: @JuniusL. Just added to an edit for you to see.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time) will probably help you understand the issue (`setState` is asynchronous), and you may also consider using [immerjs](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) to make safe mutations to state

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak if you want to put your response as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as the correct one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your code but I'm pretty sure that the problem is that you didn't provide a unique id for each item (remember that it's most of the time a bad idea to use map index for your items). The thing that you should do is to give each item a unique key and call the function based on that id.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places where you mutate the contents of `this.state`. That could cause React to be unable to detect changes in the state because the new and old state are referencing the same object. I would recommend that you don't mutate any state and instead create clones of the data object before passing the new data to setState()