# set values in react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following status of my application.

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
```

when i try to store the errors it returns validating in hook state the values ​​are replaced and only the last one is stored

```
 for (const key in book) {

            if (key == 'category_id') {
                val = validating('category', book[key], categories);
            } else {
                val = validating(key, book[key]);
            }

            console.log(key + ':' + val.status)
            setErrors({ ...errors, [key]: val });
            //console.log(errors)
        }
```

The validating function returns {status: true} or {message:'error', status:'false'}

the validation function works fine, the problem is that the objects returned by validating are not accumulated

Comment: Not sure about hooks, but doing this with older React setState would break since React doesn't get a chance to update the state inside of your for loop so errors won't change and only the last call will take effect (React has to run in between calls to render). What I would suggest is to only call setErrors once, outside of your for loop. So inside of the for loop collect the errors in a temporary object instead.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Because you thought that` this.setState(..)` is the same as `setErrors(..)`. `setErrors(..)` will retrun only the last update, so if you need to merge ( accumulate ) you need to get prevError : ``setErrors(errors=>({ ...errors, [key]: val }));`` [setHook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a state is asynchronous in nature. So before your state gets updated your next iteration of loops starts and starts a new update. You should do this instead -

```
const tempErrors = {};

  for (const key in book) {

        if (key == 'category_id') {
            val = validating('category', book[key], categories);
        } else {
            val = validating(key, book[key]);
        }

        console.log(key + ':' + val.status)
        tempErrors[key] = val;
        setErrors({ ...errors, [key]: val });
        //console.log(errors)
    }

setErrors(tempErrors);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the updates you want by using the callback variant of the set___ function.

In this case: `setErrors(errors=>({ ...errors, [key]: val }));`

You could also only callSetErrors once you finish the loop as well.

```
 for (const key in book) {

            if (key == 'category_id') {
                val = validating('category', book[key], categories);
            } else {
                val = validating(key, book[key]);
            }

            console.log(key + ':' + val.status)
            setErrors(errors=>({ ...errors, [key]: val }));
            //console.log(errors)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

More infor can be found at below link.

[Calling setState in a loop only updates state 1 time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time)

As Atin pointed out, accumulate the errors and then update the state at once

```
const tempErrors = {};

  for (const key in book) {

        if (key == 'category_id') {
            val = validating('category', book[key], categories);
        } else {
            val = validating(key, book[key]);
        }

        console.log(key + ':' + val.status)
        tempErrors[key] = val;
    }

setErrors(tempErrors);
```