# ReactJS multiple requests single state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, state, setstate

A (large) number of requests would be setting condition inside a single component:

```
  large_number_of_objects.forEach(object => {
    if(this.state.condition) {
      this.setState({
        condition: false
      })
    }
  })
```

however due uncontrollable nature of requests the set state unable to catch up while it is being set up.
Which means that a lot of requests would make it through before condition is set.
I can easily resolve it in normal (non-react) javascript code, any suggestions welcome please, thank you.

Update:
apparently the answer is hooks (found it by re-reading reactjs.org).

Comment: The question is quite unclear, but setState is asynchronous and when it resolves, the condition will be set. Could you specify more details regarding your question?

Comment: If I understood correctly you have to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time