# How to create dynamic state in for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have arrays of colors, with each color I have a gallery. I want to create and manage state for these galleries, so I can add/remove image for gallery easy.

I have code like this

```
var imgArr = new Array(colors.length)
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    imgArr[i] = colors[i].imgs
    const [gallery[i], setGallery[i]] = React.useState()
    setGallery[i](imgArr[i])
}
```

but `const [gallery[i], setGallery[i]] = React.useState()` doesn't work.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: None [of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+setstate+in+a+loop+site:stackoverflow.com&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk03Oz6KgShU4U7eZ2SNUoTAu3Sd0uA:1612281399178&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjskc2gyMvuAhVIVc0KHcysDVEQrQIoBHoECAEQBQ&biw=1792&bih=929) helped?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling setState in a loop only updates state 1 time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time)

Comment: I need to create multiple state, not just call setState in the loop.

Comment: I believe the message in almost every single one of those many, many duplicate questions is this: **Don't set state in a loop**. Best of luck to you.

Comment: I got it, it's complicated for me, but I will try to use a state to manage them all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write this inside a loop:

```
const [gallery[i], setGallery[i]] = React.useState()
```

The syntax is wrong. What you could use is a galleries state like this:

```
const [galleries, setGalleries] = useState([]);
```

Then:

```
setGalleries(colors.map((color) => color.imgs));
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-roentgen-xk9zc?file=/src/App.js:547-600. Hope this answers your question.