# Spread operator is only adding the last value in a for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display all the values for the value of born in each document in a firebase collection. My code is as follows.

```
  const [bdays, setBdays] = useState([]);

  const refresh = () => {
    db.collection("posts")
      .orderBy("born")
      .onSnapshot((ss) => {
        ss.forEach((doc) => {
          setBdays([...bdays, doc.data().born]);
        });
      });
    console.log(bdays);
  };
```

The result of `console.log(bdays)` is `[2005,2005,2005,2005]`
but it should be `[1998, 1999, 2001, 2005]` does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What does `db.collection("posts")` return?

Comment: Setting state in react is async. You should not trust the current state value for these kind of things because it can be stale. Simply change the setBdays to `setBdays((current) => [...current, doc.data().born]);` If you want to know how things works: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by one of the comments, setting state is an async process. You can accomplish what you want by using a local variable like so:

```
  const [bdays, setBdays] = useState([]);

  const refresh = () => {
    const updatedBdays = bdays;
    db.collection("posts")
      .orderBy("born")
      .onSnapshot((ss) => {
        ss.forEach((doc) => {
          updatedBdays.push(doc.data().born);
        });
      });
    setBdays(updatedBdays);
    console.log(bdays);
  };
```