# setState in a .map is giving an infinite refresh loop

Tags: reactjs

I have the following in my render

```
<select name="ip" id="ip" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
                            {redisServers.servers[config.ENV].map(i => {
                                if (i.default) {
                                    setSelectedServer(i.ip + ":" + i.port)
                                    return <option selected value={i.ip + ":" + i.port}>{i.label}</option>
                                } else if (!i.default) {
                                    return <option value={i.ip + ":" + i.port}>{i.label}</option>
                                }
                            })}
                        </select>
```

The problem is that if i add the setSelectedServer() to set a state, im receiving an infinite loop. I dont know why is that happening.

The condition is triggered only once.

the handlechange is a simple console.log

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
        let value = event.target.value
        setSelectedServer(value)
    }
```

Im doing the setstate inside the map, to set the default selected value at the beginning

Comment: because setState is callback once you setState it will rerender component and therefore infinite loop is happening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling setState in a loop only updates state 1 time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set default selected in use effect

```
useEffect(() => {
    const selected = redisServers.servers[config.ENV].find(i => i.default)
    if(selected)
    setSelectedServer(selected.ip + ":" + selected.port)
}, [])
```