# Set object in state from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am working on a ToDo list in React where users can do CRUD operations.
The last function I want to implement is updating a task.

Currently, you can load all items you already made. These items are visible in a list, each with an edit button to update the corresponding information.

Whenever a user clicks the update button, I want to load all the information in the input fields. These fields show in a pop-up menu after clicking the update button. However, I can not seem to get this to work. The input fields stay empty.

I have the following local state, no redux:

```
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    title: "",
    category: "",
    description: "",
    priority: 1, //default is 1
  });
```

The function that is bound to the "edit" button:
I also tried to set the setFormValue with the entire object but I could not get that to work either.

```
  function handleEditOpen(event) {
    for (const key in event) {
      const value = event[key];

      setFormValue({
        ...formValue,
        key: value,
      });
    }

    setEditDialogOpen(true);
  }
```

I did just learn about the async React state, hence console.log()'s don't show information instantly. However, with the for-loop in function, the state still didn't update.

One of the input fields (made with Material UI):

```
    <TextField
      required
      className="createItemCategoryTextfield"
      type="category"
      name="category"
      id="outlined-basic"
      variant="outlined"
      margin="normal"
      color="primary"
      label="Category"
      defaultValue={formValue.category}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      focused
    />
```

How would I be able to load all information of a task in my local state, to show them in the edit screen and their corresponding input fields?

Comment: Tangential, but you're setting the literal property name `"key"` to the value; did you mean `[key]`? It's not super-clear why you're setting the form value state this way, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: I've tried [key] too, what approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly update state only one by directly by this you can ignore for loop

```
setFormValue((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  ...event
}));
```

instead of setting `defaultValue` directly set `value`

Comment: That's it! I updated your answer according to my specific situation

Comment: @Craws you can ignore setState inside for loop

Comment: Could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: @Craws Since your setState is depend on previous value it is not advisable to set state in loop to read more about it you can check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35248802/11256012

In your case since your loop on event and then setting `key` as `setState key` and `value` as `setState value` so you can avoid loop and directly set as I suggested above

if you still need loop in some case what you can do create local variable and update that variable in loop and once the loop is over update state with that variable

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the value property in your material ui element - TextField *value properties*, for example

```
 const [name, setName] = useState([])

  cosnt handleChangeValue = (someValue) => {
      setName(someValue)
  }

     <TextField
     value={name}
     onChange={(e) => handleChangeValue(e.target.value}
     />
```

Comment: I've used defaultValue={formValue.category}
      onChange={handleInputChange} for that instead

Comment: If remember all the tutorials that I went through during past year,
everywhere the key property is value (html tag <input value="" />)
most likely, under the wrapper material UI, antdesign etc. - there is some condition:
defaultValue? "show default value" : "null",
but main input parameter has name value