# Changing useState() content by loops in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have declared a state in react like this:

```
const [properties,setProperties]=useState<any[]>([]);
```

and it receives arrays of objects. I can access the arrays attributes of the state in this way:

```
properties.forEach((element:any) => {
      console.log(element.propertyId)
    });
```

and it displays the values.

The problem is that I can not change the values by using "setProperties" through loops:

```
for(var i=0;i<properties.length;i++)
   {
     setProperties[i]({...properties,propertyId:"newValue"})
   }
```

I appreciate your helps

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Calling setState in a loop only updates state 1 time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time)

Comment: You should stage all the changes in a temporary object and apply them using the function callback setter of `useState`.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways you can do this, all of which involve calling `setState` only once with the new state array. Also note how we use `.map(...)` to create a copy of the old array. This is very important to signal to react that the state changed.

1. Create a copy of your state and use that to call `setState` only once.

   ```js
   const newState = properties.map((element) => ({ ...element, propertyId: "newValue" }));
   setProperties(newState);
   ```
2. Use the callback style to set the properties:

   ```js
   setProperties((oldProperties) => {
       return oldProperties.map((element) => ({ ...element, propertyId: "newValue" }));
   });
   ```